# Laravel project gives Undefined property error when run php artisan serve command

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, artisan-serve

I have a Laravel project,
this code from routes/web.php

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});
```

When I try to run 'php artisan serve' it gives Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Router::$app error,

I tried adding container instead of app

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->container->version();
});
```

then it gives 'Error: cannot access protected property'
Please let me know if anyone knows how to clear this issue and run the project

```
ErrorException: Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Router::$app

at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/em2/routes/web.php:18 at Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Router::$app', '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/em2/routes/web.php', 18, array('router' => object(Router))) (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/em2/routes/web.php:18) at Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar->{closure}()
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is there anything unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you looking for app Version. then use config('app.version'); resp. app()->version(). What @aimme has already said

```
$router->get('/', function () {
    return config('app.version');
});
```

**OR**

```
$router->get('/', function () {
   return app()->version();
});
```

Both will returned the app version. The App Version you define in the
config/app.php.

`'version' => env('APP_VERSION', '1.1.1'),`

Comment: Both methods cleared the issue but not loding the project sorry I am new to this now when I run php artisan serve and that url only gives app version number. Do I missing something? @MaikLowrey

Comment: @Sujeevan if I understood your comment correctly. As soon as you call your project: `http:localhost:8000`. You will get the app version number.  Right :-)

Comment: Yah I got that but I just wanted to run my index.php

Answer (score 1):

use `app()` helper method to access app instance from anywhere. try this

```
$router->get('/', function () {
    return app()->version();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `routes/web.php` use `Route` Facade for routing.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function (){
    app()->version();
});
```